# Dynamically added noscript tag doesn't show in view source page Angular Universal

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, angular-universal, view-source

I append noscript tag as body's child, when I run app with angular universal it doesn't show  tag in body, but I can see it on inspect element
I need to add this noscript tag not in app-root, I need to add it dynamically and as first child of body before app-root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this in my way.
I request for noscript from server.ts, add it to Html string with replace method after body tag and then send it.